# how to pass a value from one activity to last activity of flow in android

Tags: android

I have 3 classes named `activity1`, `activity2`, `activity3`. I could use following `putExtra` method to pass a String value from `activity1` to `activity2`.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(activity1.this, activity2.class); 
intent.putExtra("message", message); startActivity(intent);
```

When I need the same value in `activity3` I can use same as I did before. In case if I want to use same value in another activity that starts from `activity3`. when my activity flow is like

> `activity1`> `activity2` > `activity3` > `activity4`

is that okay to use as same?

I feel like it is not a good practice. Are there any other solutions? Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use static Method to get data from one activity to another, It can be done like this, In `activity1`

```
public class Activity1 extends Activity {

    static Activity1 INSTANCE;
    String data="FirstActivity"; 

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        INSTANCE=this; 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    public static First getActivityInstance()
    {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public String getData()
    {
        return this.data;
    }
}
```

It can be retrieved in `activity4` like this,

```
 public class Activity4 extends Activity { 

      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.main1);
          String data=First.getActivityInstance().getData();
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use SharedPreferences to store and retrieve information:

To Store:

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("YourPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
editor.putString("message", message);
editor.commit();
```

Then retrieve it in your desired activity:

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("YourPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
String value = pref.getString("message", "");
```